# Greensock timelinemax steps not smooth

Tags: css, css-transitions, gsap

I have to make a clip-path transition in different steps. However chaining `to` methods in greensock is not giving the smoothness I'm looking for, as it freezes for some milliseconds between styles. Here is my code:

```
const box = document.getElementById('box')

this.timeline = new TimelineMax({})
  .to(box, 0, { clipPath: 'polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%)' })
  .to(box, 1, { clipPath: 'polygon(20% 0%, 20% 0%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%)' })
  .to(box, 1, { clipPath: 'polygon(40% 0%, 40% 0%, 20% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%)' })
  .to(box, 1, { clipPath: 'polygon(100% 0%, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%)' })
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define an ease so it uses to the default ease which is Power1.easeOut if I'm correct, which will result in the pausing between the animations.

You could overwrite the default ease by setting

```
TweenLite.defaultEase : Power0.easeNone
```

Or write your timeline like this:

```
this.timeline = new TimelineMax({})
  .to(box, 0, { clipPath: 'polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%, 0% 0%)' }, ease:"none")
  .to(box, 1, { clipPath: 'polygon(20% 0%, 20% 0%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%)' }, ease:"none")
  .to(box, 1, { clipPath: 'polygon(40% 0%, 40% 0%, 20% 100%, 20% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%)' }, ease:"none")
  .to(box, 1, { clipPath: 'polygon(100% 0%, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%)' }, ease:"none")
```

ease:"none" is the new GSAP 3 syntax. ease:"Power0.easeNone" would be the older syntax.

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: You might want to pause your timeline on start so you have more control over the moment you want to play it.


this.timeline = new TimelineMax({paused:true})

//later in your code
this.timeline.play();